# Input file size and content do not update on macOS

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

I wrote a small web based tool, which uses a file input to read a constantly changing file. The user selects it manually (once!) and JavaScript tracks when it was changed (last file modification time and file size). If it has changed, it reads the file contents again.

This works fine in all browsers on Windows. But on macOS (tested in Safari 10.1.2 and Firefox 51.0.1) only the last modification time seems to be updated. The file size is not updated and it seems, that the file contents cannot be read anymore too. So I can not track file changes in browsers on macOS.

But why? Is this a security limitation in macOS?

Please test with following snippet. Select a file (for example a text file), see last modified timestamp and file size, then change file and look again, if size has changed. On macOS the file size doesn't change.

No jQuery please.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  window.setInterval(function() {
    var logFile = document.querySelector('#file').files[0];
    if (logFile) {
      document.querySelector('#info').innerHTML = '<br/>' +
        (new Date()).toString() + '<br/>Last modified: ' +
        logFile.lastModified +
        '<br/>Size: ' +
        logFile.size;
    }
  }, 1000);
});
```

```css
#info {
  font-family: Courier;
  font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<input type="file" id="file" />
<p id="info"></p>
```

Comment: Can you please try this and let me know. http://jsfiddle.net/assassin/698svryg/44/

Comment: Thanks Saurabh, but the size still doesn't change. Same behaviour.

Comment: @StanE, I have been trying to find an RFC to see if there a documented behaviour on this. But its hard to interpret and find the correct RFC. But just because it works in Windows, doesn't mean that it is a standard behaviour and should work on other OS too. Also I would prefer to get snapshot of a file when it was being uploaded and not a diff which is different when submission happens.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at the RFCs, Tarun! Yes, I share your opinion of the security part, but it's such a nice feature. I personally would prefer to leave the choice to the user to decide to allow continuous reading of file modifications (like the popups asking for webcam or location access). But it seems, that macOS has too strong security limitations. Btw: I'm not uploading the selected file. The file is read only locally with the FileReader API in my small project. There's no communication with the server.

Comment: it works fine on Chrome, Safari 11, Firefox 60 on MacOs high sierra

Comment: @fadomire Unfortunately, no, it does not work with Safari 11.1 or Firefox 51.0.1. Did you selected the file multiple times maybe? But yes, it works in Chrome - I already noticed that but forgot to mention here, sorry. But thanks for confirmation! Chrome seems to do the job on macOS, Windows and Linux, so I'll stick to it. Too sad, that the behaviour of different browsers does not seem to be consistent on different platforms.

Comment: IMM it is less a security measure than a performance one: Once they've got the file metadata, they won't request it every time you access the File object => less access to user's disk. I am even a bit surprised that on Windows they do... To workaround this, I can see only one solution, and which is so bad I will refrain to post it as an answer for now: you could fetch the whole file every time and check if there has been any changes. FileReader's methods and AJAX fetching a blobURI will both read the current data on disk. But unfortunately, ajax HEAD will also use the cached metadata...

Comment: But beware this means accessing the whole file on disk everytime and copying it all in memory. So maybe you should try to come up with an other alternative, for which we would need to know more about your setup: what is modifying these files? Why from the user's disk? Can't it be on a server (be it localhost) instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, the resource (selected file contents) become inaccessible in Safari when they are changed (this is why I thought it might be a security related limitation). Does it really take so much performance to retrieve the file size and last modification time? procmon (from sysinternals) show me alone for the Firefox process hundreds of file access on disk and thousands of thousands disk operations per second for all processes.

Comment: But it's fine. At least Chrome does the job and it is available on all operating systems. It's more a personal project, nothing for business customers, so it doesn't need to work in every browser. I'm happy, that it works with at least one browser. :-)

Comment: StanE you are right i did not tested properly. i selected the file multiple times. Kaiido solution with FileReader is good i think, not that much memory leak as it is garbaged collected when not needed

Comment: Actually I was a bit wrong in my statements, Safari indeed purely refuses any access to the file on disk after it has been modified. And while I though I did find a good way using `FileReader.read(File.slice(0,1))` I saw that Firefox will err only on full size reading and only if the size actually changed... Anyway, posted an answer, without code because none is good enough.

Comment: @StanE Aside Filereader API that should be the most appropriate way for a browser approach, you may consider implementing a local node.js server, even for a little personal project. This work great if you want to monitor multiple files or a whole folder. You can then use file monitoring with the built-in fs.watch or with one of the many tools that improve and simplify file watching (simply look at  'node js file monitor' in your favorite search engine)

Answer (score 3):

I don't think it is a security measure rather than simply a performance measure.
Once they've got the file metadata info, they won't request it anymore on further getting => less access to user's disk.
To be honest, I am even a bit surprised that on Windows they do request these metadata every time.

To workaround this, is not an easy task, and I would reconsider the needs for this, and if the messaging can't be done at another level (e.g from th process that does modify the files).

Indeed, both Firefox and Safari don't behave the same in this situation:

- Safari seems to create a blobURI pointing to the File as soon as you've picked it form the input, and always uses it when you try to access it later (e.g from a FileReader). The real problem here is that we can't get the new version on disk, because, for whatever reasons, this blobURI doens't seem to be a real **pointer** to the disk... But if we only want to detect file changes, then it's good for us, since we would only have to check for a `FileReader.onerror` event, which would work even with a `File.slice(0,1)` (i.e minimal I/O).
- Firefox on the other hand will trigger the FileReader's error **only** if the size of the cached metadata doesn't match with the one that has been read. This means that you would have to read the whole File at every check, and, if no error occured, double check that the data are actually the same... **But**, in this browser, you could still fetch the actual File on disk from AJAX using a blobURI, in order to get the latest version.

Comment: The performance argument doesn't make sense for me at all, but thanks for your opinion. The browser access the disk hundreds of times independently of the loaded website. How should one simple call for meta data (not even for the contents) affect the performance at all? Btw, I cannot reconsider it and I think I shouldn't either. It's a functionality, which is there but simply doesn't work correctly. If I ask JS how big a file is or when it has been changed, then it should give me correct values, which it doesn't. To make it worse, different browsers behave different. IE and opera work fine.

Answer (score 1):

I remember i had a problem reading the file input again and again before. apparently it flagged the file as modified and i had problem using the FileReader on the file after it was modified. but there is way around it

---

There is a way in that you can use to read the content of a folder. Once you have the directory entery from a drag and drop or a folder selection from a directory-file input you can loop over each file again and again to see if something has changed.

**for some reason it didn't work in SO due to sandboxing restriction** so i created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/698svryg/45/) also

```js
function traverseFileTree(entery, path) {
  path = path || ""

  if (entery.isFile) {
    // Get file
    entery.file(file => {
        setInterval(() => {
          entery.file(file => {
            console.log(file.lastModifiedDate, file.size, path)
          })
        }, 1000)
    })
  } else if (entery.isDirectory) {
    // Get folder contents
    var dirReader = entery.createReader()
    dirReader.readEntries(entries => {
      for (let entery of entries) {
        traverseFileTree(entery, path + entery.name + '/')
      }
    }, console.error)
  }
}

var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone')

dropzone.addEventListener("drop", function(event) {
  event.preventDefault()

  const items = event.dataTransfer.items

  for (item of items) {
    // webkitGetAsEntry is where the magic happens
    const entery = item.webkitGetAsEntry()

    if (entery) {
      traverseFileTree(entery)
    }
  }
}, false)

// Required for drop event to event do what we want
dropzone.ondragover = event => {
  event.preventDefault()
  return false
}
```

```css
#dropzone{
  background: black;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="dropzone">
  drop a directory here
</div>
```

Comment: Yes good idea to pass the full directory, OP might even just target **the one** file they want instead of recursive check. Also quite unfortunate that only Chrome implemented [getMetadata](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileSystemEntry/getMetadata)...