# FileReader objects return different values in Chrome and FireFox reading the same file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

The codes (angular 2) below returns different results in Chrome and Firefox after the selected file has been modified content:

```
    isExistedFiles(funcCallBack: any) {
    try {
      const r = new FileReader();
      r.onerror = function (e: any) {
        funcCallBack(0);
      };
      r.onload = function (e: any) {
        funcCallBack(1);
      };
      r.readAsText(this.files);
    } catch (e) {
      funcCallBack(0);
    }
  }
```

Result:

-Firefox: `FileReader { readyState: 2, result: null, error: DOMException,...`

-Chrome: `FileReader {readyState: 2, result: "PK ....", error: null,...`

Why it happens? And how to fix it?

Comment: what does chrome error say?

Comment: What does the DOMException in Firefox complain about?

Comment: It reported the message: "File could not be read".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They indeed have different behaviors with regard to Files that are modified on disk after user selection, and IIRC this behavior even changes on different OSes.
*(This answer is only based on observations made on macOS system it might not match yours)*

Chrome does updates the File's metadata at access.
Firefox doesn't update these metadata at access, so if the file size when you try to read it is smaller than what it was when the user selected it, then the FileReader will throw an Error.
This is because, since it uses the old metadata, it has been asked to read non-existant data.

To make it more visual, let's take the File's content at user selection:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
```

When Firefox will request the File's metadata, the OS will tell it `size: 26`.

Now, let's change this File's content to

```
abc
```

If we try to read this File through a FileReader, FF will use the metadata the OS gave to it (size:26). So it will try to read until the 26th byte of this file.
Obviously, this doesn't work... And that's your *why*.

---

So now, "how to fix it"?

Well, that depends what you mean by this... If you want to have Chrome's behavior on Firefox, you could fetch the File on disk by using a blobURI adn AJAX, actually loading it from disk to memory, and hence, with new metadata.

But beware this won't work in Safari, which does itself create a blobURI from selected Files, but which won't allow us to fetch it as a fresh one on the disk if it has been changed...

An other, uglier workaround taht would give you only the File "as it was" when user selected it, would be to create a copy of it in memory (I think FileReader.readAsArrayBuffer is the most cross-browser way to do it). But if your user did modify it, they might be disappointed to see their changes are not reflected.

So maybe the best solution, is to simply handle the error, and provide a message to your user explaining them that it's bad to modify a file that has already been selected, and offer them to select it again.

Ps: [Highly related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50370493/input-file-size-and-content-do-not-update-on-macos/50529317#50529317)